# Trying to creat MySQL database, not sure why nothing shows up on phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel, phpmyadmin

I've been playing around with my php coding for a while now. I'm trying to upload the Chicago Bears roster so that I can display it later on a webpage, but I can't get my code to work to actually upload the excel sheet to MySQL.

I have XAMPP running with MySQL and APache running. This is my code:

```
           $db_roster = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        if (!$db_roster)
        die("Unable to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());  // die is similar to exit


       //creating the database
        if (isset($_GET["button"])){
             //If create database is clicked
            if( $_GET["button"] == "create"){
                if (mysqli_query($db_roster, "CREATE DATABASE finalRoster;")){
                    echo "The database is created <br>"; //Database is created
//                else
//                    echo "unable to create database: " . mysqli_error($db_roster) . "<br>";

                mysqli_select_db($db_roster, "finalRoster");

                $cmd = "CREATE TABLE sportDatabase ( number int(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                        playerName char(50),
                        position varchar(2),
                        height char(3),
                        weight int(3),
                        age int(2),
                        experience int(2),
                        collegeName char(60)
                        );";         //Creates the table

                    echo "The Database is Ready<br>";
                }
            }
            mysqli_query($db_roster, $cmd);

            $cmd = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'bearsRoster.csv' INTO TABLE clist FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';"; 

            mysqli_query($db_roster, $cmd);

            echo "<h1>Sports contents</h1>";
            $cmd = "SELECT * FROM sportDatabase";
            $records = mysqli_query($db_roster, $cmd);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
                echo( "\t\t" . $row['number'] . $row['playerName'] . $row['position'] . $row['height']  . 
                     $row['weight']. $row['age'] . $row['experience'] . $row['collegeName'] . PHP_EOL );

            mysqli_close($db_roster);
```

Comment: `.xlsx` files are binary files. You need to export that as a comma-separated `.csv` file.

Comment: Can you provide more information such as, is the DB created but empty, or is it not created at all? Do any of your if statement echos print to screen?

Comment: @BarryThomas None of my echo statements print anything, nothing is created at all

Comment: Use `mysqli_error($db_roster)` on the queries and php's error reporting.

Comment: [I said that....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948282/trying-to-creat-mysql-database-not-sure-why-nothing-shows-up-on-phpmyadmin#comment74929271_43948282) @RiggsFolly but they seem to be answering the first ones last and last ones first; I'm out.

Comment: Oh and you created a table called `sportDatabase` but you are trying to load the data into a table called `clist`???????

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry man, its 2am here and I have visited the pub this evening

Comment: @RiggsFolly nothing for you to be sorry for buddy; hope you enjoyed every drop 'o that pint mate!

Comment: I saved the file as .csv and tried that. still nothing :(

Comment: Once its a CSV you will probably need to ignore the first line as that is column names#

Comment: @RiggsFolly Which line? i tried a cuople different ones and that did nothing as well

Comment: The first line in a csv file is normally the column heading you had in the spreadsheet, you dont want to load those and secondly they are likely to be the wrong size for your columns

Comment: @RiggsFolly i get what you mean now, I deleted that first row and redownloaded my file